# How to understand the role of the product topology conditions in the proof of Tychonoff's theorem.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I read in several texts as per Tychonoff's theorem, the arbitrary product of compact spaces is compact under the product topology. But under the box topology, the arbitrary product of compact spaces is not compact (i.e. since it is a discrete topology)

Most proofs of Tychonoff's theorem goes as follows: let $X = \Pi_{\alpha \in J}X_{\alpha}$ be a product where each $X_{\alpha}$ is compact. Assuming that $X$ is covered by open sets of the product topology, let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$ having the finite intersection property. If it can be shown that $\bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{A}}\bar{A}$ is nonempty then $X$ is compact. To prove non-emptiness of this infinite intersection, Zorn's lemma is usually invoked to obtain a collection $\mathcal{D}$ that is maximal wrt to the finite intersection property and s.t. $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{D}$... The proof then goes on to show that there's an element $x$ that interesects every element of $\mathcal{D}$ etc etc ...

But in reading the proofs, I cannot see where the role of the conditions given by the product topology come in (i.e. that any open set $O$ in the product topology should have only a finite number of product elements not equal to $X_{\alpha}$) ... in order for the proof to hold, in which part of the proof are the properties of the product topology required ? (such that if the underlying topology is the box topology the proof does not carry over) ...

Comment: What text are you following? The classic proof by the Alexander subbase lemma very explicitly uses the form of the subbasic sets; it's essential there. You seem to describe the Munkres proof in his Topology (doesn't use open covers but the FIP form and Zorn etc.) An answer will depend on that.

Comment: In the box topology $[0,1]^\omega$ does *not* have the discrete topology but nevertheless is not compact (and not connected). Be careful what you say about the box topology..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take the text that uses a proof as you describe (Munkres 2nd ed.):

First we take a family $\mathcal{A}$ in the product $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ that has the FIP. We use Zorn (or another form of AC) to extend this to a maximal family $\mathcal{D}$ with FIP.

Then in each component space $X_i$ we find $x_i \in \bigcap_{D \in \mathcal D} \overline{\pi_i[D]}$ by compactness there.

Now to see that the point $x$ formed this way is in $\bigcap_{D \in \mathcal D} \overline{D}$ we explicitly use that a basic subset of $x$ is of the form $U(x)=\pi_{i_1}^{-1}[U_{i_1}] \cap \ldots \pi_{i_n}^{-1}[U_{i_n}]$ where we have *finitely* many indices $i_1,\ldots, i_n \in I$ and by a lemma he first shows every $\pi_{i_j}^{-1}[U_{i_j}]$ is in $\mathcal{D}$ and then the FIP does the rest..

The set $U(x)$ is exactly $\prod_{i \in I} U_i$ where all $U_i = X_i$ except for the indices $i_1,\ldots, i_n$. So the proof you mention *does* explicitly use the form of the base elements of the topology.

Comment: oh yes ! thanks for that ... yes, it's Munkres that I am reading ...

Comment: @LinkL Didn't read the whole proof yet? It's quite at the end..

Comment: yes I just finished reading the proof..., if I got it right, for any $x_i \in \bigcap_{D \in \mathcal D} \overline{\pi_i[D]}$ we have that any subbasis containing $x_i$ is in $\mathcal{D}$, and that any finite intersection of these sub-bases is also in $\mathcal{D}$ due to FIP and the form of the base element..

Comment: it follows that any basis containing $x_i$ (formed from intersection of sub-bases) is also in $\mathcal{D}$ ... and eventually any open set containing $x_i$ as well is in $\mathcal{D}$.. as $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of open sets, it follows that $x \in \bigcap \mathcal{A}$ ... so I think that both the FIP property and the specific form of the base elements are used to show the key step in the proof that any basis / open set containing $x_i$ is in $\mathcal{D}$ ... is my thinking correct ?

Comment: @LinkL all the sub basic elements are in $\mathcal D$ by maximality and the lemma and $x_i \in \pi_i[D]$ for all $D$     Then FIP endures that all basic elements are too. So it’s a combo.

Comment: ok thanks a lot !